# Calling a method with parameter inside JSTL loop

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a JSP which needs to print some text which is produced by taking loop iterator and feeding it to another object (Spring bean), something like:

```
<c:forEach var="myVar" items="${myVars}">
   <c:out value="anotherObject.getFoo(myVar)"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Obviously the code above isn't valid as JSTL `.` operator only allows parameter-less invocations. I can see following solutions to the problem:

1) Scriptlets

```
<c:forEach var="myVar" items="${myVars}">
  <%
    SomeType myVar = (SomeType) pageContext.getAttribute("myVar");
    SomeOtherType anotherObject = (SomeOtherType) pageContext.getAttribute("anotherObject");
    YetAnotherType result = anotherObject.getFoo(myVar);
    pageContext.setAttribute("result", result);
  %>
  <c:out value="${result}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

The obvious con here is JSP code pollution and general ugliness.

2) Writing a tag which does whatever is done inside scriptlets. Typical example of over-engineering, yuck!

3) Decompose a collection of `myVars` and replace each `myVar` with a [dynamic proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), `InvocationHandler` of which would add extra parameter-less method to make all `getFoo()` calls through `anotherObject`. All of that would be done in the controller so JSP would stay clean and `myVar` stays the same. But at what price?

I can not add `.getFoo()` method to the `myVar` because it doesn't fit there and would break the separation of concerns.

It looks like passing parameters will be possible in JSP/EL 2.2, but I'm using Tomcat 6.0.29 which only bundles EL 2.1 API.

**Question:** can anyone suggest the cleanest approach for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've done it at the end.

Instead of passing a collection of `SomeType` instances, I am passing a map. Map keys are the same `SomeType`s and values are instances of controller-specific inner class, let's call it `SomeTypeSupplement`.

`SomeTypeSupplement` adds necessary no-arg getters and wires everything together. JSP now iterates over map entries and is able to retrieve the data via JSTL.

This way I avoid `Proxy` magic, unnecessary TLDs, keep JSPs tidy and reasonably type-safe.

Answer (score 7):

A simple Java-only "trick-fix" that works in the older JSTL version, too,
and requires no extra taglibs/config/dependencies/frameworks, etc. 
is to "wrap" the function you want to call from JSTL
in a class that extends from a `Map` class, and override its `get()` method.

As a minimal example, if you e.g. want to call the `Math.sin()` function from JSTL,
you would define a class:

```
public class Sine extends HashMap<Double, Double> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // Avoids compiler-warning

    @Override
    public Double get(Object arg) {
        Double x = (Double) arg;
        return Math.sin(x);
    }
}
```

Then in your Action execute() method, you do:

```
...
request.setAttribute("sine", new Sine());
...
```

Then in jsp you can say:

```
  ${sine[0.75]}
```

to calculate the value `Math.sin(0.75)`

JSTL will treat the variable sine as a `Map`, but you can compute and return anything you like from the get() method.

I guess it gets a bit more involved if you have more than one argument to your function,
but there should be workarounds for that, too :)

Comment: So nice and tricky, thanks a lot. for those who are new in these stuffs modelAndView.addObject("sine", new Sine()); is equivalent spring MVC version of request.setAttribute("sine", new Sine());

Answer (score 1):

If you can't abide with scriptlets (your alternative 1), I would create a custom tag for it (your alternative 2) or a custom EL function. I don't agree that it's "over-engineering", it's using the available tools for their intended purpose.

Your alternative 3, though, I don't like. If anything, THAT'S over-engineering plus it will make your system unnecessarily complex and harder for other people to follow. Adhere to the intentions of the specifications and standards you are working within. Don't make things harder or more complex for the sake of it.

Comment: If writing a JSP tag for each single method call is not over-engineering, then I don't know what over-engineering is. I am not saying option #3 is good/preferred, but neither is #2.

Comment: Well, if you are having a lot of instances where you have to explicitly invoke methods in your JSP:s, then I suggest you improve your MVC pattern and put effort towards creating a cleaner Model layer that only holds data. Then move any logic into your Controller layer.

Comment: The myVar object is an exact example of what you call Model (object that only holds data - persistence data in this case). However data I need to visualise is coming from completely different source ("`anotherObject`") and requires this model class. Your suggestion to move logic to Controller layer is close to option #3 which I suggested and you said it was a bad idea.

Comment: I was referring to your idea about dynamic proxying to achieve some AOP-like behavior, which I still maintain is overly complicated and will be hard to maintain over time. I would refactor your backing code (the controller) to extract the required information from the "anotherObject" instance and store it a cleaner model object.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just compose your object list in your backend Java code and then just use JSP to display it?

Comment: I don't think you have understood the problem I was facing. `${myVars}` already refers to a list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add a comment to the last (by time) answer of Rop, but missing "reputation", so here I am with an answer.

I shortly had the same idea with such a map, but tried to make it more generally usable, having a "DynamicMap", DynamicMapCalculator interface and letting you wrap any method call into such a map (without the need to make a new map implementation every time, just using anonymous class instantiation).

This would be the topic, if you are interested:
[A qu. of style: dynamic map JSTL hack to work around missing parameter function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426010/a-qu-of-style-dynamic-map-jstl-hack-to-work-around-missing-parameter-function)

And I would be interested in opinions there: is this something you may do without a bad conscience?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html). It is much nicer than jstl.

Comment: Vote up for a creative alternative (and a preferred on for me personally) but then again we can't always choose how we are allowed to serve up views